# MATLAB fplot's "notvectorized" warning inconsistent with testing

Tags: matlab

I've put together a function to compute the confluent hypergeometric (Kummer's) function which is essentially a truncated power series (code below).  It seems to be vectorized, i.e.:

```
xx = linspace(0, 40, 100);
yy = kummer(0.5, 1.5, xx);
all(size(xx) == size(yy))
% Returns true for this case and any other size (up to 4D) of xx that I've tested
```

However, when I try to plot the function using fplot `fplot(@(x) kummer(0.5, 1.5, x), [0 40])` I get fplot's 'NotVectorized' warning.

```
Warning: Function fails on array inputs. Use element-wise operators to increase speed. 
> In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine>getFunction
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function_I
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function
  In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine
  In fplot>singleFplot (line 223)
  In fplot>@(f)singleFplot(cax,{f},limits,extraOpts,args) (line 182)
  In fplot>vectorizeFplot (line 182)
  In fplot (line 153)
```

I know that I could just turn the warning off when I call `kummer` and turn it back on at the end of the function, but I'd like to avoid that.  Any thoughts as to what the problem might be here?  The code for `kummer` is shown below, I'm using R2016a and have tested it in R2017a with the same result:

```
function conf_hyper = kummer(a, b, z)
%kummer : Confluent hypergeometric (Kummer) function
%   Compute the confluent hypergeometric function, 1F1(a; b; z)
%
%   Parameters
%   ----------
%   a : scalar
%   b : scalar
%   z : Up to n-D matrix
%       Elements must be numeric, non-negative, and less than
%       50 in magnitude (i.e., -50 < z < 50)
%
%   Returns
%   -------
%   conf_hyper : n-D matrix
%       Confluent hypergeometric function for all values of
%       input z
%
%   Raises
%   ------
%   Error KM:InvalidValue:abInput if a or b is not a numeric,
%       real, positive, scalar
%   Error KM:InvalidValue:zInput if z is not numeric, real,
%       and less than 50 in magnitude

% Validate inputs
errorID = 'KM:InvalidValue:abInput';
errormsg = 'inputs a and b must be real, numeric, positive scalars';
validate_ab = @(x) isnumeric(x) && isscalar(x) && (x > 0) && isreal(x);
assert(validate_ab(a) && validate_ab(b), errorID, errormsg)

errorID = 'KM:InvalidValue:zInput';
errormsg = 'input z must be a numeric matrix of values in (-50, 50)';
assert(isnumeric(z) && isreal(z) && all(abs(z(:)) < 50), errorID, errormsg)

% Implement power series
% Initialize term (T), output (M), factorials (a and b), and index (i)
T = z * a / b;
M = 1 + T;
ai = a;
bi = b;
i = 1;
while any(abs(T(:)./M(:)) >= 1e-10)
    % Increment index
    i = i + 1;

    % Update rising factorials
    ai = ai + 1;
    bi = bi + 1;

    % Update term
    T = z .* T * ai / bi / i;

    % Update output
    M = M + T;
end

% Write output
conf_hyper = M;

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean by "NotVectorized"? For instance your `kummer` still has a `while` loop, which is not vectorised

Comment: @Adriaan, my understanding is that `fplot` expects that the size of the input and size of the output are equivalent.  I also think that `fplot` doesn't care what actually happens in the function, as long as this requirement is met.

Comment: MATLAB's warnings and errors are generally very clear and precise, so when it complains about vectorisation, it'll probably have to do with vectorisation, and not with sizes, since a size-error would be thrown then. I have no experience with `fplot` or this error, hence the question. I read this error as `fplot` having trouble with `a` and `b` being scalars, although I can't say why that could be a problem.

Comment: Those are fair points for sure.  Maybe I'll try hard-coding a and b to see if that makes a difference, otherwise maybe it's the while loop...

Comment: On R2017b the warning is `Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output with the same size and shape as the input arguments.` So it seems to be related to size, rather than actual vectorization of the internal operations

Comment: The warning can be produced by just running `matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine(@(x) kummer(.5, 1.5, x))`.  Unfortunately, `FunctionLine` does not have an M-file, but rather a P-file, which is obfuscated

Comment: Did a bit of troubleshooting and it seems as though the while loop is the problem - no surprise, I guess. I don’t think there’s a way around the while loop for the Kummer function so I guess warning off and warning on is the only solution.